# regex not detecting youtube links in javascript contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, youtube, contenteditable

I am using this script which detects youtube URLS pasted into the contenteditable div and replaces with the embedable code.

This works when plain text youtube URLS are pasted, but it doesn't detect or replace URLS that are pasted as clickable links.

How can i modify the code to replace both plain text youtube links and the clickable links that are pasted?

```
$.Redactor.fn.formatLinkify = function(protocol, convertLinks, convertImageLinks, convertVideoLinks)
{
    var url1 = /(^|&lt;|\s)(www\..+?\..+?)(\s|&gt;|$)/g,
        url2 = /(^|&lt;|\s)(((https?|ftp):\/\/|mailto:).+?)(\s|&gt;|$)/g,
        urlImage = /(https?:\/\/.*\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|gif))/gi,
        urlYoutube = /.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=)([^#\&\?]*).*/;

    var childNodes = (this.$editor ? this.$editor.get(0) : this).childNodes, i = childNodes.length;
    while (i--)
    {
        var n = childNodes[i];
        if (n.nodeType === 3)
        {
            var html = n.nodeValue;

            // youtube
            if (convertVideoLinks && html && html.match(urlYoutube))
            {
                html = html.replace(urlYoutube, '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/$2" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
                $(n).after(html).remove();
            }

            // image
            else if (convertImageLinks && html && html.match(urlImage))
            {
                html = html.replace(urlImage, '<img src="$1">');
                $(n).after(html).remove();
            }

            // link
            else if (convertLinks && html && (html.match(url1) || html.match(url2)))
            {
                html = html.replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
                .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
                .replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
                .replace(url1, '$1<a href="' + protocol + '$2">$2</a>$3')
                .replace(url2, '$1<a href="$2">$2</a>$5');

                $(n).after(html).remove();
            }
        }
        else if (n.nodeType === 1 && !/^(a|button|textarea)$/i.test(n.tagName))
        {
            $.Redactor.fn.formatLinkify.call(n, protocol, convertLinks, convertImageLinks, convertVideoLinks);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: You'll probably get more responses if you post a fiddle that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: can you give an example of what is and isn't matching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No links are processed since you exclude anchors (`<a>` tags) from the recursive call in this line:

```
else if (n.nodeType === 1 && !/^(a|button|textarea)$/i.test(n.tagName))
```

You should allow them by changing the regular expression to

```
/^(button|textarea)$/i
```

or use some other condition that will ensure that links (or their `href` property) are processed.

For example, if you encounter a link, you can test its `href` property against the `urlYoutube` regEx.

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/masteram/9Ma2f/) for more details.